# How to disable a image button with custom disabled button image?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a button in angularjs with a img tag where it's image changes to disabled state using css. I am using2 class 1 for enabled other for disabled.

```
<button class="save-button" ng-disabled="{{isEnabled}}"></button>
```

Please help [my plunker for the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/aX7SuKzENRA8EL4LHd4C?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using ng-disabled, the expression should be a true/false value to determine if the button is actually disabled.

The code shoud look like this:

```
<button class="save-button" ng-disabled="!isEnabled" ng-click="test()"></button>
<button title="Toggle" ng-click="isEnabled = !isEnabled">toggle</button>
```

Now the button is disabled when the 'isEnabled' value is set to false.

I fixed your **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NkRiJFiUzysF0XT9gt9G?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, also how can I change my button css to something which shows it is disabled?

Comment: you could use ng-class to give a class name depending on the 'isEnabled' variable. example: ng-class="{'save-button': isEnabled, 'save-button-disabled': !isEnabled}"